# SwiftUI TabView: Howto handle reordering?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When having this `TabView` running on an iPhone (Simulator), the tabs are shown, together with a "...More" indicator. It offers the option to reorder the tabs; however, when e.g. dragging "8" to the "3" location, the "8" is shown until it is tapped; then, it's restored to "3" again.

How can the tab order be accessed, and made persistent (i.e., restored after app restart)?

```
struct IRTabbedBar: View {


    @State var selectedTab: Tab = .t1


    var body: some View {

        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {

            Text("1")
                .tabItem { Text("1") }
                .tag(Tab.t1)

            Text("2")
                .tabItem { Text("2") }
                .tag(Tab.t2)

            Text("3")
                .tabItem { Text("3") }
                .tag(Tab.t3)

            Text("4")
                .tabItem { Text("4") }
                .tag(Tab.t4)

            Text("5")
                .tabItem { Text("5") }
                .tag(Tab.t5)

            Text("6")
                .tabItem { Text("6") }
                .tag(Tab.t6)

            Text("7")
                .tabItem { Text("7") }
                .tag(Tab.t7)

            Text("8")
                .tabItem { Text("8") }
                .tag(Tab.t8)

        }
    }
}


struct IRTabbedBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {

        IRTabbedBar()
    }
}


extension IRTabbedBar {

    enum Tab: Hashable {

        case t1
        case t2
        case t3
        case t4
        case t5
        case t6
        case t7
        case t8
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to store the tabs into an array and retrieve them from an array. Then store that array in app state (and possibly written to UserDefaults or something).

Comment: But the question remains: how can be detected that the tab items are reordered? There is no "onReorder" or similar modifier available.